# RxJava2 timer and combineLatest

Tags: android, timer, rx-java, kotlin

kind of new to RxJava2
I'm having problems with `timer` and `combineLatest` e.g.:

```
Observable.combineLatest(
  Observable.timer(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS).map { TimedData(it) },
  locationDataSource.listen(),
  sensorDataSource.listen().
  Function3 { timedData, location, sensorEvent -> Combined(timedData, location, sensorEvent) }
).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()).observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()).subscribe {
  Log.d(TAG, "Timer -> " + it.timedData)
}
```

What's happening is that  `timedData` is only being update once, then it never fires again, all the other observables are begin updated.
I've found https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/issues/1717  but it's from 2014, so I would think it's already solved.

Is this still happening because of BackPressure?

Comment: See the [javadoc](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/1.x/javadoc/rx/Observable.html#timer(long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit,%20rx.Scheduler)). It is firing exactly once and you need `interval`.

Comment: damn it, I guess I did confuse the operators. You are correct! I'll try it when I arrive home, but you should probably write as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That works as designed. `Observable.timer` schedules some task for single delayed execution. **If you want something to be executed periodically try `interval` instead of `timer`.**

```
Observable.interval(0,5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```